Accordion is working but transition not working
I made an accordion using html, CSS and JavaScript and the accordion is working fine but the problem is that the transition that I'm applying on it is not working properly and I don't know why so please guide me
I tried adding transition property on all classes in hopes that any single one will work or will be inherited someway (I know its stupid of me but still tried to get the results so added) but its not working and don't know where I am messing up. My first question in here so if asked the question in wrong way then let me know


let FAQs = document.querySelectorAll(".faq");
FAQs.forEach((faq) => {
  faq.onclick = function () {
    if (!faq.classList.contains("active")) {
      FAQs.forEach((content) => {
        content.classList.remove("active");
      });
      faq.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      faq.classList.remove("active");
    }
  };
});
#FAQs {
  margin: 128px 0px;
  padding: 0px 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 64px;
}
.accordion {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 32px;
  width: 100%;
}
.faq {
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 18px;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.question {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}
.question img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.faq.active .question img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.answer {
  display: none;
}
.faq.active .answer {
  display: block;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}
.faq active {
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}
<section id="FAQs">
  <h1 class="bold40 textBg">FAQs</h1>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="border">
      <div class="faq">
        <div class="question">
          <h1 class="bold24">Can we expect long term updates?</h1>
          <img src="data/chevronDown.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
          <p class="reg16">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis
            perspiciatis porro minus earum nostrum, odit nobis culpa voluptatem
            delectus cumque inventore soluta quas ipsam exercitationem molestiae
            dolorum ratione, eligendi asperiores ex hic eius iure? Veritatis
            cumque ratione quod? Sit sed laboriosam odit modi id non consectetur
            ipsam minima quo eos?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <div class="faq">
        <div class="question">
          <h1 class="bold24">How much secure is the game?</h1>
          <img src="data/chevronDown.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
          <p class="reg16">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis
            perspiciatis porro minus earum nostrum, odit nobis culpa voluptatem
            delectus cumque inventore soluta quas ipsam exercitationem molestiae
            dolorum ratione, eligendi asperiores ex hic eius iure? Veritatis
            cumque ratione quod? Sit sed laboriosam odit modi id non consectetur
            ipsam minima quo eos?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <div class="faq">
        <div class="question">
          <h1 class="bold24">Can I gift my accuount to others?</h1>
          <img src="data/chevronDown.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
          <p class="reg16">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis
            perspiciatis porro minus earum nostrum, odit nobis culpa voluptatem
            delectus cumque inventore soluta quas ipsam exercitationem molestiae
            dolorum ratione, eligendi asperiores ex hic eius iure? Veritatis
            cumque ratione quod? Sit sed laboriosam odit modi id non consectetur
            ipsam minima quo eos?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <div class="faq">
        <div class="question">
          <h1 class="bold24">
            What happens to my account if I dont log in for long period of time?
          </h1>
          <img src="data/chevronDown.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
          <p class="reg16">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis
            perspiciatis porro minus earum nostrum, odit nobis culpa voluptatem
            delectus cumque inventore soluta quas ipsam exercitationem molestiae
            dolorum ratione, eligendi asperiores ex hic eius iure? Veritatis
            cumque ratione quod? Sit sed laboriosam odit modi id non consectetur
            ipsam minima quo eos?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




display: is likely your culprit, have you tried using opacity in your animation instead?

transition from display:none to display:block (and back) requires transition-behavior: allow-discrete along with some other majicks ... and even then it won't work as expected in firefox yet

@dalelandry when opacity is used it means that the text is there but is not being shown while the display none will make the text disappear

Probabaly not the most elegant approach, but you could use some JS to add/remove display after the opacity fires.

@imhvost thanks for the link, it solved my issue, once again thanks a lot
